# How to open other page on Click of button

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.5

I am working on an application for IOS .I made a menu bar which contains buttons , menu bar should be on each page of application. I made many **View controller scenes** , I want the functionality like this : when i click on any button it should open a **View controller scenes**.

How to open a **View controller scenes** on click of button ? I don't want to add other existing **View controller scenes** on my current **View controller scenes** as a subview. I want to open other existing scenes independently.

Comment: use custom tabbar functionality and implement as menu bar. like this http://www.martinhoeller.net/2011/05/07/custom-tab-bars/

Comment: I already made it, now i wants to open other existing scenes on click of buttons. here it this application they are adding as a subview of current view

Comment: @Gup OP doesn't want the other VC added as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Insert View :**

```
ButtonView *buttonView = [[ButtonView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ButtonView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
buttonView.view.frame = CGRectMake(yourFrame);
[self.view addSubview:buttonView.view];
```

**2) Remove View :**

```
[buttonView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Can anyone explain me the Reason for DownVote ?

Comment: There are some things in the World, that is still un-explainable. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into the following

- Navigation controller
- Tab bar controller custom implementation

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, just replace YourViewController with the name of the .xib you would like to load.

```
YourViewController *yvc = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:yvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This goes inside your `IBaction` for the navigation button, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into UINavigationController or UITabBarController. There are other ways too. The navigation controller is the easiest. Apple documentation has everything you need.